# Android Studio reading xmls from sdcard

Tags: java, android

I'm trying learn more about java as much as I can but I don't know if I'm searching wrong questions.

Basically I want to understand how apps can possibly put files on the SDcard that the user can edit and that will directly affect the app.

For example. The SD card folder contains colors.xml, is it possible for the user to edit that file to change say the background of the app? Or is there a better way? Such as an in app text editor that can directly edit the color.xml?

Thank you.

Comment: A good start is to read the [Storage Options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) on Android

Comment: `Basically I want to understand how apps can possibly put files on the SDcard .... ` Well apps can create files,  read files and write to files. So what is it that you want to know exactly? `...that the user can edit and that will directly affect the app.`. xml files on the device storage do not affect your app. Not before edit. Not after edit. Please be much clearer about what you have in mind.

Comment: @greenapps. The app t-ui launcher does this editing an xml file in the user sd files affects the app. I basically want to understand how I could implement a way for the user to edit an xml that would affect the app.

Comment: `The app t-ui launcher does this editing an xml file in the user sd files affects the app` ??? Sorry, dont understand a word of this. Where are you talking about?

Comment: @greenapps there is a launcher that gives the user an theme. xml, this can then be edited and it then affects the app. I know what I mean in my head. I'm not great at explaining

Comment: Ok. But having an xml file on the micro SD card that influences your app is one. Editing such a file is two. But not different from editing other text files. So only talking about editing will not bring much.  You should have started telling us who put that xml file on your micro SD card. And what you coded so that that file would influence your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PreferenceActivity` or `PreferenceFragment` (in case you want Fragment):
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html

They are default Android UI to modify settings stored in `SharedPreferences`:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Thank you for the links. Is there any open source app that demonstrate this as well? Something I could play with?

Comment: You can follow some tutorial on the internet, it should be easy. Look at the https://alvinalexander.com/android/android-tutorial-preferencescreen-preferenceactivity-preferencefragment

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've started working on understanding how it works. I've made a simple shared pref app available here:
https://github.com/Arxhtects/Saved-Colorchange/

That sort of does what I want it to do. Thank you everyone for your suggestions.